# How to make generic function using void * in c?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I have an `incr` function to increment the value by `1`
I want to make it generic,because I don't want to make different functions for the same functionality.

Suppose I want to increment `int`,`float`,`char` by `1`

```
void incr(void *vp)
{
        (*vp)++;
}
```

But the problem I know is `Dereferencing a void pointer is undefined behaviour`. Sometimes It may give error :`Invalid use of void expression`.

My `main` funciton is :

```
int main()
{

int i=5;
float f=5.6f;
char c='a';

incr(&i);
incr(&f);
incr(&c);

return 0;
}
```

The problem is how to solve this ? Is there a way to solve it in `C`only

or

will I have to define `incr()` for each datatypes ? if yes, then what's the use of `void *`

Same problem with the `swap()` and `sort()` .I want to swap and sort all kinds of data types with same function.

Comment: Does c++ have postfix increment for integral types? Why you want to redefine it?

Comment: In C11 you can use `_Generic`: http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html

Comment: @Yola: It's just a demo.. actually I have to make lot may functions in my project which should work on may datatypes even on structs, And I don't want to create that many functions

Comment: Did you consider using typeof

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can implement the first as a macro:

```
#define incr(x) (++(x))
```

Of course, this can have unpleasant side effects if you're not careful. It's about the only method C provides for applying the same operation to any of a variety of types though. In particular, since the macro is implemented using text substitution, by the time the compiler sees it, you just have the literal code `++whatever;`, and it can apply `++` properly for the type of item you've provided. With a pointer to void, you don't know much (if anything) about the actual type, so you can't do much direct manipulation on that data).

`void *` is normally used when the function in question doesn't really need to know the exact type of the data involved. In some cases (e.g., `qsort`) it uses a callback function to avoid having to know any details of the data.

Since it does both sort and swap, let's look at qsort in a little more detail. Its signature is:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int(*cmp)(void const *, void const *));
```

So, the first is the `void *` you asked about -- a pointer to the data to be sorted. The second tells qsort the number of elements in the array. The third, the size of each element in the array. The last is a pointer to a function that can compare individual items, so `qsort` doesn't need to know how to do that. For example, somewhere inside qsort will be some code something like:

```
// if (base[j] < base[i]) ...
if (cmp((char *)base+i, (char *)base+j) == -1)
```

Likewise, to swap two items, it'll normally have a local array for temporary storage. It'll then copy bytes from `array[i]` to its temp, then from `array[j]` to `array[i]` and finally from `temp` to `array[j]`:

```
char temp[size];

memcpy(temp, (char *)base+i, size);              // temp = base[i]
memcpy((char *)base+i, (char *)base+j, size);    // base[i] = base[j]
memcpy((char *)base+j, temp, size);              // base[j] = temp
```

Comment: Thanks, I was out for an hour , A little doubt about above explanation. According to that I suppose every time I will typecast the void pointer to char type and perform operations based on their size , right ?

Comment: These functions `memset,memmove,memcpy` all takes `void*` as argument ,It means they do the same as converting to `char*`

Comment: @Omkant: No. You need to cast to `char *` when you want to do pointer math. When/if you don't need to do math on the pointers, the code will typically receive a `void *` from its client, and return that same `void *` back to the client code when needed.

Answer (score 13):

Using `void *` will not give you polymorphic behavior, which is what I think you're looking for.  `void *` simply allows you to bypass the type-checking of heap variables.  To achieve actual polymorphic behavior, you will have to pass in the type information as another variable and check for it in your `incr` function, then casting the pointer to the desired type OR by passing in any operations on your data as function pointers (others have mentioned `qsort` as an example).  C does not have automatic polymorphism built in to the language, so it would be on you to simulate it.  Behind the scenes, languages that build in polymorphism are doing something just like this behind the scenes.

To elaborate, `void *` is a pointer to a generic block of memory, which could be anything: an int, float, string, etc.  The length of the block of memory isn't even stored in the pointer, let alone the type of the data.  Remember that internally, all data are bits and bytes, and types are really just markers for how the logical data are physically encoded, because intrinsically, bits and bytes are typeless.  In C, this information is not stored with variables, so you have to provide it to the compiler yourself, so that it knows whether to apply operations to treat the bit sequences as 2's complement integers, IEEE 754 double-precision floating point, ASCII character data, functions, etc.; these are all specific standards of formats and operations for different types of data.  When you cast a `void *` to a pointer to a specific type, *you* as the programmer are asserting that the data pointed to actually is of the type you're casting it to.  Otherwise, you're probably in for weird behavior.

So what is `void *` good for?  It's good for dealing with blocks of data without regards to type.  This is necessary for things like memory allocation, copying, file operations, and passing pointers-to-functions.  In almost all cases though, a C programmer abstracts from this low-level representation as much as possible by structuring their data with types, which have built-in operations; or using structs, with operations on these structs defined by the programmer as functions.

You may want to [check out the Wikipedia explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_pointer#C_and_C.2B.2B) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do exactly what you're asking - operators like increment need to work with a specific type.  So, you *could* do something like this:

```
enum type { 
    TYPE_CHAR,
    TYPE_INT,
    TYPE_FLOAT
};

void incr(enum type t, void *vp)
{
    switch (t) {
        case TYPE_CHAR:
        (*(char *)vp)++;
        break;

        case TYPE_INT:
        (*(int *)vp)++;
        break;

        case TYPE_FLOAT:
        (*(float *)vp)++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it like:

```
int i=5;
float f=5.6f;
char c='a';

incr(TYPE_INT, &i);
incr(TYPE_FLOAT, &f);
incr(TYPE_CHAR, &c);
```

Of course, this doesn't really give you anything over just defining separate `incr_int()`, `incr_float()` and `incr_char()` functions - this isn't the purpose of `void *`.

The purpose of `void *` is realised when the algorithm you're writing doesn't care about the real type of the objects.  A good example is the standard sorting function `qsort()`, which is declared as:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

This can be used to sort arrays of any type of object - the caller just needs to supply a comparison function that can compare two objects.

Both your `swap()` and `sort()` functions fall into this category.  `swap()` is even easier - the algorithm doesn't need to know anything other than the size of the objects to swap them:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *ap = a;
    unsigned char *bp = b;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned char tmp = ap[i];

        ap[i] = bp[i];
        bp[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Now given any array you can swap two items in that array:

```
int ai[];
double ad[];

swap(&ai[x], &ai[y], sizeof(int));
swap(&di[x], &di[y], sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 2):

*Example for using "Generic" swap.*

This code swaps two blocks of memory.

```
void memswap_arr(void* p1, void* p2, size_t size)
{      
      size_t         i;
      char* pc1= (char*)p1;
      char* pc2= (char*)p2;
      char  ch;

      for (i= 0; i<size; ++i) {
        ch=     pc1[i];
        pc1[i]= pc2[i];
        pc2[i]= ch;
      }
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
int main() {
     int i1,i2;
     double d1,d2;
     i1= 10; i2= 20;
     d1= 1.12; d2= 2.23;
     memswap_arr(&i1,&i2,sizeof(int));     //I use memswap_arr to swap two integers
     printf("i1==%d i2==%d \n",i1,i2);     //I use the SAME function to swap two doubles
     memswap_arr(&d1,&d2,sizeof(double));      
     printf("d1==%f d2==%f \n",d1,d2);
     return 0;
}
```

I think that this should give you an idea of how to use one function for different data types.

Comment: How does that help with the OP's increment requirement ?

Comment: He asked for: *"I want to swap and sort all kinds of data types with same function."* and that's what I answered :) I thought that a good example can make a good explanation. I was trying to help, not to confuse :)

Comment: Combined with a macro, `#define swap(x, y) swap_impl(&x, &y, sizeof x)` and boom, there is no need of using the sizeof operator always. Good example!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this may come off as a non-answer to the broad question "**How to make generic function using void * in c?**".. but the problems you seem to have (incrementing a variable of an arbitrary type, and swapping 2 variables of unknown types) can be much easier done with macros than functions and pointers to void.

Incrementing's simple enough:

```
#define increment(x) ((x)++)
```

For swapping, I'd do something like this:

```
#define swap(x, y)                  \
({                                  \
        typeof(x) tmp = (x);        \
        (x) = (y);                  \
        (y) = tmp;                  \
})
```

...which works for ints, doubles and char pointers (strings), based on my testing.

Whilst the incrementing macro should be pretty safe, the swap macro relies on the `typeof()` operator, which is a GCC/clang extension, NOT part of standard C (tho if you only really ever compile with gcc or clang, this shouldn't be too much of a problem).

I know that kind of dodged the original question; but hopefully it still solves your original problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type-generic facilities (C11 standard). If you intend to use more advanced math functions (more advanced than the `++` operator), you can go to `<tgmath.h>`, which is type-generic definitions of the functions in `<math.h>` and `<complex.h>`.

You can also use the `_Generic` keyword to define a type-generic function as a macro. Below an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define add1(x) _Generic((x), int: ++(x), float: ++(x), char: ++(x), default: ++(x))

int main(){
  int i = 0;
  float f = 0;
  char c = 0;

  add1(i);
  add1(f);
  add1(c);

  printf("i = %d\tf = %g\tc = %d", i, f, c);
}
```

You can find more information on the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and more soffisticated examples in this post from [Rob's programming blog](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html).

As for the `* void`, swap and sort questions, better refer to [Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469686/9256892)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast your pointer to concrete type before dereferencing it. So you should also add code to pass what is the type of pointer variable.