# Using void for other data types.

Tags: c

So I have got this piece of code:

```
int compare(const void *c1, const void *c2)
{
    assert(c1 && c2);
  char a = *(const char*)c1;
  char b = *(const char*)c2;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

What it basically does is it gets two pointers c1 and c2 of any data type and checks who is bigger than the other. I would like this to work for any data type I recieve but it seems to make problems when I'm sending double or float.
What should I add/change?

Comment: `checks who is bigger than the other` that's not _exactly_ what it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make generic function using void \* in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469381/how-to-make-generic-function-using-void-in-c) - And many other requests for dirty hacks the like.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Worse: It is implementation-defined.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a callback for `qsort` or some similar function?  It's simply not possible to write a "generic" one; it's fundamental to the design of `qsort` that while it does not know the data type being sorted or how to order the values, you have to, meaning that you always have to write a specific comparison function.

Comment: What if `c1` and `c2` point to structs?  How can there possibly be a single, generic algorithm to compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in C.  C has no run-time type information (RTTI).

What you're asking is to compare some number of bytes pointed to by `c1` to some number of bytes pointed to by `c2`.  We don't even know how many bytes there are, let alone what type they're supposed to represent.  So there's no way to write a single, "generic" function which can magically decide which of a potentially infinite number of comparison algorithms to apply.

---

Addendum: If it were possible to do this, `qsort` would have been designed with a function like this built in, and you wouldn't have to write your own comparison function. The fact that the designers of `qsort` punted on this responsibility, and kicked the problem of writing a comparison function back to you, the user, pretty much proves that it can't be done.

It's an unfortunate fact of life that whenever you call `qsort`, you have to write your own custom comparison function, pretty much every time; you can't write one general-purpose one, once, and be done with it.

Comment: How can I use a function like that so that it would fit any type of data type I recieve?

Comment: @LamaEu. You cannot, because you cannot know ahead of time the data type of the sorting requirements, or even if ascending or descending. And as commented above, suppose you have a struct array and you wish to sort on the second field. Or worse, sort on the third field if the second fields are equal.

Comment: Note: with cleaver use of `_Generic()`  and `qsort_s()`, code can be written that handles _many_ basic types.  Yet as you answer, no fully general solution.